# MVVM Cross View to display list in 2 columns

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

In MVVM Cross what widget/view can be used to display a list of objects in 2 columns? Does a `MvxListView` suffice?

Ie, instead of just vertically listing each object, display them in 2 vertical columns like the last picture below:

[image]     [image]

I am aware how to bind and display a vertical list of objects, thats easy, but how could I display one list of objects into 2 columns? Maybe I need to create a custom binding?

PS: Is there a reference of MVVM Cross widgets? I've searched and haven't found any documentation. I am looking for a comprehensive list; MvxFrameView, MvxImageView, MvxListView, etc.

ViewModel:

```
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private List<Category> _cats;
    public List<Category> Cats
    {
        get { return _cats; }
        set
        {
            _cats= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Cats);
        }
    }
}
```

Android View (simple vertical layout):

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Cats"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_category" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a `MvxGridView` instead:

```
<Mvx.MvxGridView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="4dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Cats"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_category" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where did you find out about all these views (MvXGridView, MvxImageView, etc.)? I cant find reference documentation for this (for the views or MVVM Cross classes)

Comment: I didn't find a Special list about these controls.. just look at this page :https://github.com/MvvmCross There are several samples and tutorials about different sections